# <input type="button" /> does not call Spring controller in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I call a spring controller method on a button click in my JSP. It works fine in Firefox. But does not do anything in Internet Explorer 8.

Following is the JSP code

```
<a href="maintenance.html"  >
    <input type="button" value="Search" name="action"/>
</a>
```

Following is the Spring Controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/","/maintenance"})
public String navigateToMaintenance() {     
    return "maintenance"; 
}
```

Comment: Why do you use a button nested inside an anchor tag?

Comment: I am using bootstrap for UI and I am supposed to use buttons. Is there any other way to call a controller using button ?

Comment: @Parag <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active" role="button">Primary link</a>

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your controller. Its a Microsoft Standard that doesn't allow button inside anchor. Remove your `a` tag and change your code like this

```
<input type="button" value="Search" name="action" onClick="location.href='maintenance.html'"/>
```

Or

You can remove button and style your anchor like button

Comment: @Parag You should accept the answer if it worked in order for future readers to know that it worked without having to read the comments :)